# Story about an immortal man who could not die from old age

Tags: story-identification

I think that in the story there was an immortal man who could not die from old age. I think he could die from other things, though. It involved some battle that he had to relive on the other side of or something. I remember him telling some kids about when he was born, and they laughed at him. Also, I believe it was a short story, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi Jack and welcome to the SFF SE. What does _some battle that he had to relive on the other side of or something_ mean? On the other side of what?

Comment: @JohnRennie Presumably on the side opposing the one he previously participated in.

Comment: Most immortal men that you encounter don't die from old age; it's kind of their distinguishing chacteristic. Please provide additional info.

Comment: If he fought a battle twice, once on each side, does that mean he time travels as well? If so more info about how the time travel works would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

*[Time Enough for Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love)* (1973) by Robert A. Heinlein is a fixup of several magazine stories featuring ageless, immortal Lazarus Long.

In the final segment, "Da Capo", he travels back in time to 1917 and interacts* with his family.  Lazarus's grandfather, thinking Lazarus is just another young man of military age, browbeats him into joining the Army and going off to France to be mortally wounded.

Lazarus Long was introduced in 1941 in several stories that were fixed up in 1958 into *[Methusaleh's Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah%27s_Children)*, He also appears in *[The Number of the Beast --](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_(novel))* (1980), *[The Cat Who Walks Through Walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Walks_Through_Walls)* (1985), and *[To Sail Beyond the Sunset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Sail_Beyond_the_Sunset)* (1987).

**quiet, you.*

Comment: I can't believe that Heinlein went back in time and ripped off Futurama. What a hack :-(

Comment: Doesn't fit very well. They don't laugh at him, and he didn't participate in the battle at the end on the other side previously.